# mysql subquery in select unknown column

Tags: mariadb

I have a subquery in the select statement that I need to find a count based on the base query.   If I hard code the course_id that needing the count for it works (other then the count is for just the same course not all listed) but when I change it to use the listed course_id it returns the 1054 - Unknown column error.

Error SQL

```
SELECT 
 c.course_id, 
 c.course_name,
 (SELECT COUNT(wpt_users_id)
  FROM (SELECT course_activity.wpt_users_id, course_activity.course_id, min(course_activity.course_activity_entry_dt)
  FROM wpt_user_subscriptions
  JOIN course_activity ON course_activity.wpt_users_id = wpt_user_subscriptions.wpt_users_id
  WHERE wpt_user_subscriptions.wpt_subscription_id = 35 
  AND course_activity.course_id = c.course_id
  GROUP BY course_activity.wpt_users_id, course_activity.course_id) sub1) as course_count
FROM `wpt_subscription_course` sc
JOIN course c ON c.course_id = sc.course_id
WHERE sc.`wpt_subscription_id` = 35
```

Returns: MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'c.course_id' in 'where clause'

Will run SQL:

```
SELECT 
 c.course_id, 
 c.course_name,
 (SELECT COUNT(wpt_users_id)
  FROM (SELECT course_activity.wpt_users_id, course_activity.course_id, min(course_activity.course_activity_entry_dt)
  FROM wpt_user_subscriptions
  JOIN course_activity ON course_activity.wpt_users_id = wpt_user_subscriptions.wpt_users_id
  WHERE wpt_user_subscriptions.wpt_subscription_id = 35 
  AND course_activity.course_id = 9
  GROUP BY course_activity.wpt_users_id, course_activity.course_id) sub1) as course_count
FROM `wpt_subscription_course` sc
JOIN course c ON c.course_id = sc.course_id
WHERE sc.`wpt_subscription_id` = 35
```

Any thoughts to why it's not working when it's spelled correctly yet not working.

Environment specs:

```
[[Database server]]
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 5.5.41-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10

[[phpMyAdmin]]
Version information: 4.4.8, latest stable version: 4.4.10

[[Web server]]
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.41-MariaDB
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.4.16
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more indentation makes it more obvious:

```
SELECT  c.course_id, c.course_name, 
      ( SELECT  COUNT(wpt_users_id)
            FROM  
              ( SELECT  ca.wpt_users_id, ca.course_id,
                        min(ca.course_activity_entry_dt)
                    FROM  wpt_user_subscriptions AS wus
                    JOIN  course_activity AS ca ON ca.wpt_users_id =
                                                  wus.wpt_users_id
                    WHERE  wus.wpt_subscription_id = 35
                      AND  ca.course_id = c.course_id   -- HERE
                    GROUP BY  ca.wpt_users_id, ca.course_id
              ) sub1
      ) as course_count
    FROM  `wpt_subscription_course` sc
    JOIN  course c ON c.course_id = sc.course_id        -- HERE
    WHERE  sc.`wpt_subscription_id` = 35
```

I think subqueries can see tables only in the immediately surrounding query.

Maybe this works and gets the right answers??

```
SELECT  c.course_id, c.course_name, course_count
    FROM  `wpt_subscription_course` sc
    JOIN  course c ON c.course_id = sc.course_id
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  COUNT(*) course_count, ca.wpt_users_id, ca.course_id,
                min(ca.course_activity_entry_dt)
            FROM  wpt_user_subscriptions AS wus
            JOIN  course_activity AS ca ON ca.wpt_users_id = wus.wpt_users_id
            WHERE  wus.wpt_subscription_id = 35
              AND  ca.course_id = c.course_id
            GROUP BY  ca.wpt_users_id, ca.course_id 
      ) sub1
    WHERE  sc.`wpt_subscription_id` = 35
```